# getMonth() JavaScript Function get a wrong value

Tags: javascript, date

when i wanna to extract a Month value i got an incorrect value :

```
date2 =  new Date('Mon Dec 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Maroc)')
date2.getMonth() // --> i got 11 !!
```

i can increase the value by one but is not the best the solution

Any help please

Comment: [MDN getMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Answer (score 1):

The `getMonth()` function starts at zero.
Therefore, January will return zero and December will return 11.

You can read more about the date object and the getMonth function here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 1):

The `getMonth()` return value is zero-based.

Quoting the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth#Returns)

> The value returned by `getMonth()` is an integer between 0 and 11. 0 corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.